# Most efficient way to flatten an array of dictionaries containing arrays

Tags: swift

Let's say I have an array of dictionaries, and each contains an array of letters. Like this:

```
let dicts = [["letters" : ["a","b","c"]],
             ["letters" : ["d","e","f"]]]
```

What is the most efficient way to create a flattened array of all the letters from all the dictionaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`reduce(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/2298686-reduce) for that.

```
let array = dicts.reduce([]) { $0 + ($1["letters"] ?? []) }
print(array) // ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
```

**Edit:** As @Hamish suggested a link in comment simplest solution is having less time, so if you are having large amount of data then you can use `forEach` closure with array.

```
var result = [String]()
dicts.forEach {      
    result.append(contentsOf: $0["letters"] ?? [])
}
```

Comment: Awesome... Super bro :D

Comment: Great, thanks. I guess this should be a separate question, but how could you do this if your array was of type [String:Any]? Won't allow the '+' operator in this case.

Comment: @JamesWhite Then it should go like `{ $0 + ($1["letters"] as? [String] ?? []) }`

Comment: Got it. Thanks so much.

Comment: Note that this is pretty bad performance-wise; the accumulating array will be needlessly copied at each iteration.

Comment: @NiravD I did – [here are my results](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/a54f059b8b30225b766630971f511eb2) for a release build. `reduce` with an accumulating array does not fare well at all with large sequences.

Comment: @Hamish Thanks for the information. Simplest solution using for loop having less time on My Mac so I edited my answer with `forEach` closure.

Comment: https://airspeedvelocity.net/2015/08/03/arrays-linked-lists-and-performance/ is an interesting article about the (bad) performance of using `reduce` to "map" an array. It is a bit old but still valid. That should change with the implementation of https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0171-reduce-with-inout.md.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `flatMap()` to map each dictionary to the corresponding
letters array and join the results:

```
let dicts = [["letters" : ["a","b","c"]],
             ["letters" : ["d","e","f"]]]

let letters = Array(dicts.flatMap { $0["letters"] }.joined())
print(letters) // ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
```

This is effective insofar as no additional intermediate arrays are
created during the join. As @Hamish pointed out below, the
intermediate `[[String]]` can be avoided with

```
let letters = Array(dicts.lazy.flatMap { $0["letters"] }.joined())
```

Comment: You could always get rid of the intermediate `[[String]]` with `Array(dicts.lazy.flatMap { $0["letters"] }.joined())` :)

Comment: @Hamish: You are right, thanks! However, I could not observe a significant difference in performance when running your test code multiple times.

Comment: Ah interesting w.r.t not being able to notice a difference – the difference is definitely there for me in a release build (not so much in debug), although it does become less prominent as the input size grows. Still thought I would mention it though!

Comment: @Hamish: Try changing the order of the tests (do the lazy method first). Does that make a difference (it does in my test)? What happens if you execute the tests multiple times (`for _ in 1...10 { <your do blocks> }`) ?

Comment: Ah yes, you're right – it was the ordering of the tests that did it. There's indeed no noticeable difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any one of these. You don't need to specify the key name of the dictionary.

**Solution 1**

```
    let array = dicts.reduce([]) { $0 + ($1.values.reduce([]) { $0 + $1 }) }
    print(array) // ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
```

**Solution 2**

```
    let array = dicts.flatMap { $0.values.joined() }
    print(array) // ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
```